# How to mock xlsx / sheeetjs with jest?

Tags: jestjs, mocking, sheetjs

Here is some code using xlsx library (=sheetjs):

```
import { read } from 'xlsx';

export default function foo(file){
  return read(file);
};
```

and here is a unit test for it:

```
import foo from '../../../src/components/upload/demo';
it('foo', () => {
  const mockedXlsx = {
    read: () => 'mocked_result'
  };
  jest.mock('xlsx', () => mockedXlsx);

  const mockedFile = {
    arrayBuffer: () => {}
  };
  spyOn(mockedFile, 'arrayBuffer');
  const result = foo(mockedFile);
  expect(result).toBe('mocked_result');
  expect(mockedFile.arrayBuffer).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

My package.json includes following dependency:

```
"xlsx": "https://cdn.sheetjs.com/xlsx-0.19.0/xlsx-0.19.0.tgz"
```

Instead of calling my mocked `read` function, the original function is called and I get the error

```
TypeError: e.slice is not a function
```

=> How should I adapt my code, so that `jest.mock` replaces the original read function?

I already tried to

a) Include `__esModule: true` in mockedXlsx

b) Include an entry for xlsx in jest.config moduleNameMapper:

```
'^xlsx$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/xlsx/dist/xlsx.full.min.js'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, I changed the import to

```
import xlsx from 'xlsx';
```

I use the same import in the test and then, instead of `jest.mock('xlsx',...)` I can use

```
spyOn(xlsx,'read')
```